# Java Array Output Confusing

Tags: java, arrays, string

Taken from this site: https://www.journaldev.com/770/string-byte-array-java

```
package com.journaldev.util;

public class ByteArrayToString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] byteArray = { 'P', 'A', 'N', 'K', 'A', 'J' };
        byte[] byteArray1 = { 80, 65, 78, 75, 65, 74 };

        String str = new String(byteArray);
        String str1 = new String(byteArray1);

        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println(str1);
    }
}
```

Why is the output:

> PANKAJ
>
> PANKAJ

I can't see how it isn't:

> PANKAJ
>
> 806578756574

Comment: `80` is not the same thing as `"80"`.

Comment: The string constructor takes in an array of bytes and interprets them as characters. The byte 80 represents the character `'P'`, etc.

Comment: ASCII codes are used under the hood when you convert the byte array to string

Comment: I had an inkling that was the case. Thank you for helping me see how to identify it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`byte[] bytes` constructor will parse the data contained, as @khelwood said it comments, the number are the ASCII representation of the letter so 80 represents a 'p' character.

if you want your output as you want, you should use

```
String[] srtArray = {"P","A"...}
String[] srtArray = {"80","65"...}
```

In the case of `{ 'P', 'A'...}`, they are already encoded but number will be converted since they are stated as `numbers` and not `string`. "80" is not the same as 80.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public class ByteArrayToString {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] byteArray = { 'P', 'A', 'N', 'K', 'A', 'J' };
        byte[] byteArray1 = { 80, 65, 78, 75, 65, 74 };

        String str = new String(byteArray);
        String str1 = new String(byteArray1);

        System.out.println(str);
        for (byte b : byteArray1) {
            System.out.print(b);
        }
        //System.out.println(str1);
    }
```

}
Program output

Comment: Usually code only answers are discouraged. Instead, post an in-depth explanation alongside.